# Listing according to constraint

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a 3x3 matrix, check each of the columns starting from the first one, and if a column contains 1 or -1 the output is x, otherwise the output is y. Then list the sequence of these x,y as a vector.  For example, let A={{2,1,1},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}, then f is the vector where f(1)=y, f(2)=x, f(3)=x, according to the given matrix

I tried the following but it needs to be revised:

```
 For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, For[z = 1, z <= 3, z++,  If[A[[z, k]] == 1 || A[[z, k]] == -1,  f[[k]] = y,  f[[k]] = x;  ];  ];  ]; f[[1]], f[[2]], f[[3]]
```

I also tried this one but in this version if a column has 1 then output is x otherwise the output is y

```
For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, If [A[[1, k]] == 1  || A[[2, k]] == 1 || A[[3, k]] == 1, f[[k]] = y,  f[[k]] = x; ]; ];
```

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Your result is not consistent with the operation described.

Comment: Thanks  I just wrote my try, but It not works. Thanks @Bob Hanlon, I revised it. It is consistent now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose and then Map

```
{{2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} // Transpose // 
 Map[If[MemberQ[#, 1] || MemberQ[#, -1], x, y] &]
```

Or

```
{{2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} // Transpose // 
 Map[If[ContainsAny[#, {1, -1}], x, y] &]
```

```
{y, x, x}
```

Comment: Thanks for the  code , I understand this one is considering if a column has 1 then x and otherwise y, For adapting  if a column has 1 or -1 then x, do we need to only change MemberQ[#, 1] as MemberQ[#, 1,-1] ?

Comment: @gunes fixed code.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering How we can adapt your code to for loop case. I suppose we should start as f = {}; For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,  after that how can we go on?

Comment: @gunes It's not recommended to use `For` in mma （Though mma has this function）

Comment: @wuyudi @gunes `...//Map[If[MemberQ[#, 1 | -1], x, y] &]` is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

{y, x}[[1 + Boole @* MemberQ[1 | -1] /@ Transpose @ list]]
```

{y, x, x}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

ArrayReduce[FirstCase[#, 1 | -1 :> x, y] &, list, 1]
```

> `{y, x, x}`

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[AnyTrue[Abs@# == 1 &], Transpose@list] /. {True -> x, False -> y}
```

> {y, x, x}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, i_ :> If[! FreeQ[Transpose[list][[i]], 1 | -1], x, y]]

(*{y, x, x}*)
```

Comment: Please try with `{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}` ? OP requires looking through columns.

Comment: @Syed Thanks for the feedback! See the update, please.